# How to include the value of an array in a query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, search

I have the following array:

```
 $rqt="SELECT * FROM `client_gestion_compte` WHERE `id_company`='".$societe['id']."' AND `id_gestionnaire_client`='".$_SESSION['id']."'" ;
 $res=mysql_query($rqt);

 $values = array();
 while($donnees=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {
     $values[] = $donnees['compte'] ;
 }
```

I would like to use the value of this array in order to make a search query in the database. I have to use all value of the array, but the trouble is that I don't know how many items are in the array so I can not do manually where this criteria LIKE $value and so on...

So I've tried like this.

```
`$sql="SELECT * FROM `debiteur` INNER JOIN `creance` ON `creance`.`n_doss` = `debiteur`.`n_doss` WHERE `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`nom` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' AND `creance`.`code_client` LIKE '%".$values."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`prenom` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`raison_sociale` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`siret` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`adresse` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`adresse2` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' Or `debiteur`.`ville` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`code_postal` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`tel` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`tel2` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' Or `debiteur`.`fax` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`fax2` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' Or `debiteur`.`gsm` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`gsm2` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`e_mail` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' GROUP BY `creance`.`n_doss`  ";
```

The trouble is on this line  `creance.code_client LIKE '%".$values."%'`

Because I never know how to search with all the custom values of the array and not only with one value like that values[1] for example.

Comment: Insert random rant against `mysql_*` functions here - switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for good.

Comment: @moonwave99 or mysqli_ , why would you only mention PDO, when there are two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `debiteur` 
INNER JOIN `creance` ON `creance`.`n_doss` = `debiteur`.`n_doss` 
WHERE {...}
AND (`creance`.`code_client` LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `creance`.`code_client` LIKE '%", $values) . "%')
{...}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `foreach` loop or `implode` to traverse all the elements of the array,

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `debiteur` INNER JOIN `creance` ON `creance`.`n_doss` = `debiteur`.`n_doss` WHERE `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`nom` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' AND ";
 foreach($values as $v)  {
  $sql .= `creance`.`code_client` LIKE '%".$v."%' OR " ;
 }

 $sql .= " `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`prenom` LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR `creance`.`id_company`=".$societe['id']." AND `debiteur`.`.....";
```

Comment: I understand, but what about the query? WIll it load three time or just take the first result or the last when I will make a mysql_query($sql) ?

Comment: it will use all the values in array `$values` and concatenate it with an `OR`. Hence, you will get the resultset as a whole. By the way, using `implode` (as Gustonez answered) is a better solution, as it avoids a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rqt="SELECT * FROM `client_gestion_compte` WHERE `id_company`='".$societe['id']."' AND `id_gestionnaire_client`='".$_SESSION['id']."'" ;
 $res=mysql_query($rqt);

 $values = array();
 while($donnees=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {
     $values[] = $donnees['compte'] ;
 }

 $value_query=implode(",",$values);

 //Place it like this in your query

 creance.code_client IN ('".$value_query."')
```